# Head branch unknown

Tags: git

I have a set of files that needs to be stored in Github.

I have an account and created a repository TL1Project and initialized the folder with the set of files with `git init`.

Now when I push the project nothing is happening. When I entered `git remote show origin`, my head branch is unknown.

How can I fix this issue?

```
root@ubuntu:/home/pr/Pythonprojects/Info/I2# git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/P1981/TL1Project.git
  Push  URL: https://github.com/P1981/TL1Project.git
  HEAD branch: (unknown)
```

Answer (score 7):

I just had the same problem. Sadly graveti's answer didn't fix it for me. Going ahead and pushing to the repo fixed my problem. Like this;

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: `git push -u origin master`, `-u` set upstream for git pull/status

Answer (score 6):

New repo have no branches, github proposes some instructions to get started, here they are

```
echo "# your-repo-name" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/your-repo-name.git
git push -u origin master
```

This [video](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-how-to-write-a-javascript-library-setting-up-github) helps to understand details

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that a master branch is not created until your first commit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like somehow you don't have the master branch for your local repository. So you can just create it:

```
git checkout -b master
```

You can then do a `git status` to see if the master branch has been created, and if it's your current branch.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem. Upon trying to run `git remote add origin repo-origin`, I got `fatal: not a git repository`. To fix this I noticed my local repo was not being tracked by git. So, I first ran: `git init`. This initialized tracking. Then ran `git checkout -b main`, because `git branch -M main` gave me a ref error. Meaning, there was no head? After that, I added my files and committed them followed by `git push origin main`. Refreshed GitHub, and everything was there.